# nodeschool learnyounode node.js module FILTER LS exercise

Tags: node.js

Below is the exercise 5 of nodeschool learnyounode module

Create a program that prints a list of files in a given directory, filtered by he extension of the files. You will be provided a directory name as the first agument to your program (e.g. `/path/to/dir/`) and a file extension to filter by as the second argument.

For example, if you get 'txt' as the second argument then you will need to filter the list to only files that end with `.txt`.

The list of files should be printed to the console, one file per line and have to use asynchronous I/O.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var mydir = process.argv[2];
var ext1 = process.argv[3]
fs.readdir(mydir, function(err, files){
  if(err){
    throw err
  }
  //console.log(files);
  files.forEach(function(filename){
    var ext = path.extname(filename);
    if(ext == ext1){
      console.log(filename);
    }
  });
});
```

When i run this i got the correct output, But when i verify output using learnyounode actual result not matching with expected result

Dont know where i went wrong. Can someone give me the solution plz???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is just a typo. You're doing this:

```
    if(ext == ext){ // you're comparing the same variable
      console.log(filename);
    }
```

, but you should be doing this:

```
    if(ext === ext1){ // try to use '==='
      console.log(filename);
    }
```

Other thing: they're not considering the `.` of `.txt` in the input, so you have to append this in your variable `ext1` because `.extname(file)` returns the extention with the `.`:

```
var ext1 = '.' + process.argv[3];
```

Comment: Sorry i wrongy typed over here. even if it is ext1 i cant complete the exercise though i got that output.

any suggestions?

Comment: See the second part of my answer, about how you're setting the `ext1` var. Maybe that's your problem: you're not considering the `.`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the official solution:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

fs.readdir(process.argv[2], function (err, list) {
  list.forEach(function (file) {
    if (path.extname(file) === '.' + process.argv[3])
      console.log(file)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to solve this exercise :

```
var fs = require('fs');
    function endsWith(str, suffix) {
        var s = str.slice(str.length - suffix.length - 1);
        if (s == "." + suffix)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
};


fs.readdir(process.argv[2], function (err, list) {
    if (process.argv[3]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (endsWith(list[i], process.argv[3]))
                console.log(list[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filePath = process.argv[2];
var fileType = '.' + process.argv[3];

fs.readdir(filePath, function(err, list) {
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    if (list[i].match(fileType)) {
        console.log(list[i]);
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I came up with, if you want other solutions to problem:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = process.argv[2]; //first argument
var extension = process.argv[3]; //second argument
var re = new RegExp("."+extension, "g"); //a regexp that matches every string that begins with a dot and is followed by the extension, i.e. .txt

fs.readdir(path, function callback(err, list){ //read the directory
  if (!err) { //if no errors occur run next funtion
    list.forEach(function(val) { //take the list and check every value with the statement below
      if(re.test(val)) { //if the .test() rexexp-function does not match it will return a false, if it does it will return true
        console.log(val); //if it matches console log the value
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing missing in your code is the concatenation of '.' before the file extension type.

> var extension = '.'+ process.argv[3];

You can then do the comparison and printing.

Comment: That right there is a quote, not a code block. Codes should be indented with 4 spaces, not with the greater-than (>) sign.

Answer (score 0):

thats how i solved it

```
var fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path")

var dir = process.argv[2],
    ext = "."+process.argv[3];
function borer(callback){
    fs.readdir(dir,function(err,list){
        if(err){
            console.log(err) 
        }else{
            var row = list.filter((a)=>{
                var regexp = new RegExp(ext+"$","ig") 
                if( a.search(regexp) > -1 ){
                    callback(a)
                }
            })

        }
    })
}
function print(f){
    console.log(f)
}

borer(print)
```

Comment: It is better to add an explanation; not just give raw code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given uses the path module from Node JS package. The solution below doesn't use path, instead relies on simple deconstruction of given filename and using the parts needed.

-Import fs module

```
    var fs = require('fs');
```

-Extract the path and ext name required from cmd line

```
    let filePath = process.argv[2];
    let extName = process.argv[3];
```

-Use (readdir) method to read the contents of a directory. The names of files inside the directory will be returned in the form of an array.

```
    fs.readdir(filePath, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;

      data.forEach(element => {
```

-Take each element and split it into filename and extension name

```
      let temp = element.split('.');
      let tempSplit = temp[1];
      if(tempSplit === extName) {
        console.log(temp[0] + '.' + temp[1]);
      }
    });
```

Whole code for reference:

```
    var fs = require('fs');

    let filePath = process.argv[2];
    let extName = process.argv[3];

    fs.readdir(filePath, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;

      data.forEach(element => {
      let temp = element.split('.');
      let tempSplit = temp[1];
      if(tempSplit === extName) {
        console.log(temp[0] + '.' + temp[1]);
      }
    });
```