# Wondering how to debug Node.js learnyounode "filter ls" exercise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working through the learnyounode exercises. Specifically "filter ls". If you're not familiar with this exercise please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042480/nodeschool-learnyounode-node-js-module-filter-ls-exercise) description of it.

**Here is the [official solution](https://github.com/brunops/nodeschool-solutions/blob/master/learnyounode/filtered-ls.js):**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
fs.readdir(process.argv[2], function (err, list) {
  list.forEach(function (filename) {
    if (path.extname(filename) === '.' + process.argv[3]) {
      console.log(filename);
    }
  });
});
```

**Here is my solution:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var directory = process.argv[2];
var fileExtension = "." + process.argv[3];

function sortFiles (callback){

    fs.readdir(directory, function(err,files){

        if(err) return callback(err);

        callback(null,files);
    });
};

sortFiles(function(err,files){
    var fileExt = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < files; i++){
        debugger;
        fileExt = path.extname(files[i]);

        if(fileExt === fileExtension){
            console.log(files[i]);
        };
    };
});
```

**The problem:**

My code outputs nothing. As far as I can tell, there biggest difference between my code and the official solution is the following:

```
      list.forEach(function (filename) {
        if (path.extname(filename) === '.' + process.argv[3]) {
        console.log(filename);
      }
```

vs:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < files; i++){

        fileExt = path.extname(files[i]);

        if(fileExt === fileExtension){
            console.log(files[i]);
        };
    };
```

**2 Questions:**

*1)* How do I debug this code? I tried `node debug node.js`. From that I can see that when my directory is a folder that contains a cs file and a js file, files is an array, but each index contains "".

*2)* Why is my approach of a simple for loop not working? Why did they chose `.foreach`? Is there any reason other than it being more terse?

Comment: Where is `fileExt` defined?

Comment: I forgot to add a var; the code in the question now reflects my current code. Doesn't work still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

2) Forgot to check the `length`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                         --^--
```

But `forEach` reads better, and it is more idiomatic.

Comment: I checked node-inspector out yesterday and it quickly led me down a rabbit hole that is "StrongLoop". I'm really interested in getting that running at some point  soon but want to keep my concept count low for now. Pretty excited to debug node in the browser though.